# Error with django-grappelli 2.4.8

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-grappelli

I have added grappelli to my project and I get the following javascript error in the console when opening list view in the admin interface
I work with django 1.5.5 and grappelli 2.4.8

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("tr input.action-select").actions()')
```

the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("tr input.action-select").actions();
        });
    })(grp.jQuery);
</script>
```

base.py
grapelli is before django.contrib on the list

```
'grappelli',
'django.contrib.admin',
```

anyone know what it could be about?

steps taken so far: clear cache

Comment: Did you do `python manage.py collectstatic` before starting the server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that I use amazon s3, so I needed to delete my old admin and grappelli files before using collect static again, once I did that, it worked.